# How to reload the configuration Jenkins from the command line?

Tags: linux, jenkins, ansible

I installed and configured Jenkins through the system configuration management (ansible). Through ansible create jobs, install modules and configure them. After installing and configuring the module authorization crowd2, to reload the config via http://localhost/jenkins/reload does not work, as required authorization. To generate an authorization token, you must first log in, but this is not desirable. Can I have root access to reload the config?

P.S. Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 4):

`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -noCertificateCheck -s https://jenkins.example.com:8443/jenkins/ reload-configuration`

Comment: `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins.example.com -auth ID:PWD_or_APIToken reload-configuration `

Comment: To download the jar: `wget ${jenkins_server}/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar`

Answer (score 2):

You can generate crumb:

`curl -u 'admin:password' -X GET http://localhost:8090/crumbIssuer/api/json | jq`

Response looks like:

```
{
  "_class": "hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer",
  "crumb": "1348b504383211402ce562e0b46b3691",
  "crumbRequestField": "Jenkins-Crumb"
}
```

Then take `crumb` field value and use it in reload call:

`curl -u 'admin:password' -X POST http://localhost:8090/reload -H 'Jenkins-Crumb: 1348b504383211402ce562e0b46b3691'`

Comment: I'm getting: Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Answer (score 0):

One easy workaround is to use Ansible to restart the Tomcat or the Jenkins service (depending on how Jenkins is hosted).

With this solution, the configuration will be reloaded.

If Ansible is used to create a fresh install of Jenkins, nobody will be using Jenkins. So restarting the service can be an acceptable solution ;)

Comment: Restart can not be done, because in the future it can be performed at a time when running jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) with the `reload` command.  For example:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://jenkins.example.com/ reload
```

Or you could use the `create-job` to create jobs in the first place, removing the need to reload the configuration.

The CLI lets you authenticate with an SSH key, so that may be more amenable to being run from Ansible.

Comment: jenkins-cli.jar requires authentication, as well as API.

Comment: Meant to use the private key to jenkins-cli, I need to use the account. That is, I need to log in, and then save the public key for the admin account, and then use jenkins-cli. I need to make a reload without having to use accounts. So the task.

Comment: Yes, because reloading *should* require authentication. You can either disable security, or provision the Jenkins server already with a public key using Ansible — there's no need to log in. Or restart the web server, as the other answer mentions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s [JENKINS_URL[ -auth [USER:PASSWORD] reload-configuration

Answer (score -4):

Go to Configurations -> Reload Configuration from Disk

Comment: This is how we do in jenkins UI.