# Helm Jenkins JCasC Automatic Reload of Configuration as Code

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-confuration-as-a-code

I have created a Jenkins instance in which I am using Jenkins Configuration as Code (JCasC) and I am using Helm to manage the deploys/upgrades.

As a test, I created a welcome-message.yaml file:

```yaml
jenkins:
  systemMessage: "JCasC used to configure Jenkins"
```

I placed this into a directory called JCasC in the Helm chart for Jenkins:

```
helm-charts/
  charts/
    jenkins/
      jcasc/
        - welcome-message.yaml
```

In the templates folder, I place the jenkins-custom-casc-config.yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: jenkins-custom-casc-config
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "jcasc/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

in

```
helm-charts/
  charts/
    jenkins/
      templates/
        - jenkins-custom-casc-config.yaml
```

In values.yaml I create the config map info for the volumes:

```yaml
  volumes:
    - name: jenkins-custom-casc-config
      configMap:
        name: jenkins-custom-casc-config
  mounts:
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home/custom_casc_configs
      name: jenkins-custom-casc-config
```

This all works as it should, placing the welcome-message.yaml in `/var/jenkins_home/custom_casc_configs` properly. I have set `CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG` to look for files in the standard CASC directory as well as the new custom directory.

```yaml
containerEnv:
  - name: CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG
    value: "/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs,/var/jenkins_home/custom_casc_configs"
```

For sidecars, I have this set up in the values.yaml file:

```yaml
sidecars:
    configAutoReload:
      enabled: true
      image: kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar:1.24.4
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      resources: {}
      reqRetryConnect: 10
      folder: /var/jenkins_home/casc_configs
```

No matter what I do, the JCasC is never reloaded when I perform a `helm upgrade...` even though the new/updated config files are placed into the `/var/jenkins_home/custom_casc_configs` directory. I can intervene by going to the Configuration as Code console in the Jenkins UI and updating the configuration by manually entering the directory and applying.

I have crisscrossed the web looking for the answer, but there is no clear solution. How do I make JCasC automatically reload when I perform an upgrade via Helm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official Jenkins Configuration as Code (JCasC) plugin documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/21806a5b67199aa1acfb6f6a24bb9a77f682f3a2/demos/kubernetes-helm/README.md?plain=1) for the Kubernetes Helm implementation does not mention a "`folders`" attribute for the sidecar configuration.
Instead, it uses a singular "`folder`" attribute, which means the sidecar is configured to monitor only *one* directory for changes.

```yaml
sidecars:
  configAutoReload:
    enabled: true
    image: shadwell/k8s-sidecar:0.0.2
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    sshTcpPort: 1044
    label: jenkins_config
    folder: /var/jenkins_home/casc_configs
    # Additional configurations
```

In your case, the sidecar is set to monitor the `/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs` directory. Since you are also using a custom configuration directory (`/var/jenkins_home/custom_casc_configs`), the sidecar, in its current state, will *not* monitor this directory.

---

If feasible, you might need to move all JCasC files to the same directory that the sidecar monitors (`/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs`). That will make sure any changes in this directory trigger the auto-reload.

---

But if you need to keep the custom configuration directory separate, another option is to implement a custom solution (such as a script or a secondary sidecar) to monitor the `/var/jenkins_home/custom_casc_configs` directory and trigger a reload when changes are detected.

Something that continuously monitors the specified directory for changes. That can be achieved using a shell script with a simple loop and checksum comparison:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Define the directory to monitor
MONITOR_DIR="/var/jenkins_home/custom_casc_configs"

# Initialize the last checksum
LAST_CHECKSUM=$(find $MONITOR_DIR -type f -exec md5sum {} + | md5sum)

while true; do
    # Calculate current checksum
    CURRENT_CHECKSUM=$(find $MONITOR_DIR -type f -exec md5sum {} + | md5sum)

    # Compare checksums
    if [ "$LAST_CHECKSUM" != "$CURRENT_CHECKSUM" ]; then
        echo "Change detected, reloading JCasC..."

        # Command to reload JCasC
        # Example: using Jenkins CLI or Jenkins REST API call
        # jenkins-cli.sh -s http://jenkins:8080 reload-configuration
        # or
        # curl -X POST http://jenkins:8080/reload-configuration --user user:token

        # Update last checksum
        LAST_CHECKSUM=$CURRENT_CHECKSUM
    fi

    # Wait for a bit before checking again
    sleep 60
done
```

The script needs to be deployed and run within the Jenkins environment, either with:

- an [`init` container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) in your Kubernetes pod to deploy and run the script. The script can be started as a background process during pod initialization.
- a [sidecar container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/sidecar-containers/), with the script running  in its own container alongside Jenkins. That method provides isolation from the Jenkins container.
- a direct execution, where you include the script directly in the Jenkins container and run it as a background process. That can be done through a custom Docker image or by mounting the script into the container and running it.

The script can then reload the JCasC using either:

- the [Jenkins CLI](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/), if it is set up, to trigger a [configuration reload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34798897/6309).
- the [REST API](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/), used to send a POST request to the reload URL.
- direct file manipulation, modifying a tracked file to trigger a reload.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I will try a couple of the things that you have specified to see what the best solution is for our environment.

Comment: The only issue we had was trying to figure out how to get the custom JCasC files loaded into `/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs` as the pods would fail to start when we changed the specification for the mount to be that directory. Again, thank you for the detailed answer. We will keep plugging away at this until we have something workable.

Comment: @JayBlanchard OK, please let me know if you find a viable solution.

Comment: For whatever reason, we were unable to load the additional files into `/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs` so we opted for the custom directory and using the shell script as suggested. It works.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Great, well done!